# Java Android - close application (notifications) after swiping in recents

Tags: java, android, notifications

How can I close application (or just remove all notifications) after swiping in recent apps? In API level <= 22, it's working automaticly (just force quit the application) But API level 23 - marshmallow+ application after swiping is not closed and notification is also not closed.

How i can kill the notification or application after swiping off in recnet apps?

I'm showing notification onPause and removing it on onResume... but when I swipe the application in recent apps (application is closed - after re-opening the app have new initialization) but notification is still here and I need to kill this notifi.

Thanks for your answers guys.

BTW: I try the Service (onTaskRemoved()) but this function is never be called and I also do not know why..

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "VYKAL";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
```

EDIT: notification

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(compat, MainActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(compat, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(compat)
                .setSmallIcon(getSmallIcon(laststate))
                .setContentText(lastcontent)
                .setContentTitle(compat.getString(R.string.APPLICATION_NAME))
                .setContentIntent(intent).setOngoing(true);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(compat.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);
        rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft, getLargeIconSRC(laststate));
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.title, compat.getString(R.string.APPLICATION_NAME));
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.text, lastcontent);
        mBuilder.setContent(rv);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) compat.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Is it a sticky notification?

Comment: IDK what is sticky notification, just normal notification using NotificationCompat.Builder @Viv

Comment: You can see the notification at the bottom of question @Viv

Comment: Try removing all notifications using NotificationManager.cancelAll() on onDestroy of the Application class

Comment: Nope, when I swipe application from recent apps the destructor is not called :-) that's the problem @Viv

Comment: Have you tried using Service.startForeground() ?

Comment: hm, services probably does not working.. that's weird i have it in my manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a new Service with onTaskRemoved()... example:

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "VYKAL";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand()");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        MainActivity.closeActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

- register it in manifest
- start it on your main activity